# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getElementById' on 'Document': 1 argument required, but only 0 present

Tags: javascript, html

I have PHP write some code inside my HTML web page that reads...

```
// BEGIN FORM
    echo "<div class='comment-input'>";
    echo "<span class='postContainer-Titleheader inline'>"."username"."</span>";

    echo "<form id='form".$post_id."' >";
    echo "<textarea class='comment-textarea' placeholder='Coment here...' name='".$post_id."' ";
    echo " onkeydown='textAreaResize(".$post_id.")' onkeyup='textAreaResize(".$post_id.")' id='".$post_id."'></textarea>";
    echo "<input type='submit' >";
    echo "</form></div>";
// END FORM
```

I then have a Javascript function called textAreaResize which reads

```
function textAreaResize(id) // this resizes the text areas as necessary
{
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    element.style.height = "auto";
    element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
};
```

onkeyup and onkeydown pass an id to the javascript function which then uses it to process it.  The code **works pefectly** as shown however, when i change the code and change the id to something like

```
echo " onkeydown='textAreaResize(text".$post_id.")' onkeyup='textAreaResize(text".$post_id.")' id='text".$post_id."'></textarea>";
```

(Notice how i added "text")
The JavaScript function breaks and i get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getElementById' on 'Document': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
```

However all the arguments are there.  This is something i've been trying to solve for a few hours now but cannot seem to figure out.  What is my problem?

Obviously its telling me that i'm not passing an argument.  But i am.  All i did was ass a little more to the id of the texarea.

Comment: I can't believe your original code works, since you are passing a variable containing a DOM element to `textAreaResize`, not an ID. Either way, I believe you are looking for `this`: `onkeydown='textAreaResize(this)'`. Also, `echo`ing HTML is bad because it makes your code hard to maintain. Learn more about events: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: strings passed should be quoted as well, `" onkeydown='textAreaResize(\'text".$post_id."\')' ... etc`

Comment: Yeah i realize that echoing seems strange out of context but this is merely a snippet of a large forum system so i am forced to echo the code.  It was also strange to me that the original code works as well!

Comment: When you are using `echo`, you can almost always directly include the HTML in the document. E.g. instead of writing `<?php echo '<span>'.$bar.'</span>'; ?>`, you'd write `<span><?php echo $bar; ?></span>`. But that's not related to the problem (well, partly because it makes the markup more difficult to write if it is in a string).

Comment: Changing line of code to 

echo " onkeydown='textAreaResize(\"text".$post_id."\")' onkeyup='textAreaResize(\"text".$post_id."\")' id='text".$post_id."'></textarea>";

Doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Felix: After changing the code up and integrating "this" i was able to get it to work.  Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the original question however it is a useful fix.  If you want to answer i'll grab it.